# How do i filter angular mat-table using multiple keywords and/or partial match

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, mat-table

I am trying to filter my mat table by matching exact strings for a column for example these are two rows in one column:

1. Jack wants a puppy
2. Jack wants a puppy dog

If i search for **Jack dog** it should only show the second row containing the string. So I should be able to applyFilter using multiple keywords to display results. I have tried customizing filter predicate but the filter fails when I type in **Jack dog**. it passes if i type in **Jack wants a puppy dog** exactly. Is it possible to customize search to match just the letters irregardless of space and characters? i.e., **jack do** should only display one result. Here is my approach

```
this.dataSource.filterPredicate =
      (data: UserData, filters: string) => {
        const matchFilter = [];
        const filterArray = filters.split(/[\s,]+/);
        const columns = (<any>Object).values(data);
        // OR be more specific [data.name, data.race, data.color];

        // Main
        filterArray.forEach(filter => {
          const customFilter = [];
          columns.forEach(column => customFilter.push(column.toLowerCase().includes(filter)));
          matchFilter.push(customFilter.some(Boolean)); // OR
        });
        return matchFilter.every(Boolean); // AND
      }
  applyFilterSimple(filterValue: string) {
    const filtersSimple = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
    this.dataSourceSimple.filter = filtersSimple;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this custom pipe, maybe you can drop it into your ts file and use it there.
It takes 3 parameters the array of objects, the property to filter by (can be used by multiple objects), and the string the user entered. it return the array just filtered.

```
  transform(items: object[], propToFilterBy: string, searchText: string): object[] {
    if (!items) {
      return [];
    }
    if (!searchText) {
      return items;
    }
    searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
    var searchArray = searchText.split(' ');

    return items.filter(elem => elem[propToFilterBy] && this.checkArray(elem[propToFilterBy].toLowerCase(), searchArray) );
  }

  checkArray(str: string, searchArray: string[]) {
    for (let i = 0; i < searchArray.length; i++) {
      if ( !str.includes(searchArray[i]) ) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

The truth is, i added some code for your use case, and i didnt heavily test this code, so it might still need some tweaking.

Comment: so using pipe is better approach than further modifying filterpredicate ? should be simpler than that not sure why filterpredicate wouldn't work on this scenario

Comment: so i would call `transform()` on  `<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilterSimple($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filtrer">
  </mat-form-field>` I am kinda new to angular.

Comment: I have tried implementing  stackoverflow.com/a/48471388/9217586  problem is if i have data like: 
  `{position: 1, name: 'Hydrôgen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrôgen two', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrôgen two three', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},`

input of `Hydrogen three` will not work which is what I am trying to fix

Comment: i see your issue, you still need help?

Comment: Yes, I have triad all i can think of but I cant seem to get a work around. and neither would reverse filtering work searching for a match of `dog jack`

Comment: you can play with the data that is in the MatTableDataSource. the array is held in the data field. But you will want to hold the original array somewhere for the future if the user switches the search term. so ill do the folowing in tghe function it calls:
 if(!this.masterData) {
      this.masterData = this.dataSource.data;
    }
    this.dataSource.data = this.masterData.filter(elem => elem.Action && this.checkArray(elem.Action.toLowerCase(), searchArray) );
this should use the checkArray function i wrote in the anser